# Node imports using Feeds module giving errors

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am trying to create nodes by importing (CSV import) nodes through [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.
My CSV file is in (`guid, title`) format.

I got the following errors while importing the file.

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in _node_extract_type() (line 379 of XXXX\modules\node\node.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in node_export_import_types_check() (line 458 of XXXX\sites\all\modules\node_export\node_export.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in node_export_import_types_check() (line 458 of XXXX\sites\all\modules\node_export\node_export.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in _node_extract_type() (line 379 of XXXX\modules\node\node.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in node_export_import_types_check() (line 458 of XXXX\sites\all\modules\node_export\node_export.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in node_export_import_types_check() (line 458 of XXXX\sites\all\modules\node_export\node_export.module).
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in _node_extract_type() (line 379 of XXXX\modules\node\node.module).

And the following error:

> Error encountered during import. Node types unknown on this site: . No nodes imported.

Comment: Please give more information regarding the same. Which fields you are trying to import. In CSV you should include mandatory fields

Comment: I am using guid, title fields in the csv file and defined mapping in the Feeds importer.

Comment: It seems you are using node_export module. Can try to disable this module then try with CSV import using Feeds?

Comment: Hi, How to import the CSV file. Should we link it to the content type? If I use that particular content type, it is importing file and displaying a message "There are no new nodes."

Comment: Hope these references will help you 1) http://d6-support.yale.edu/book/export/html/260   2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4  3) https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/feeds/